# How to collect addresses with a specific token

Tags: contract-development, tokens, addresses, erc-20

I run a local eth node on my server and would like to collect all addresses which hold a specific token.

In addition I'd like to supply them with another token. 
One way I researched is to send them the new token via an airdrop contract. This one is taken from [OmiseGo](https://github.com/omisego/airdrop/blob/master/contracts/Airdropper.sol).

```
contract Airdropper is Ownable {

function multisend(address _tokenAddr, address[] dests, uint256[] values)
onlyOwner
returns (uint256) {
    uint256 i = 0;
    while (i < dests.length) {
        ERC20(_tokenAddr).transfer(dests[i], values[i]);
        i += 1;
    }
    return(i);
}
```

Do you have a suggestion how to get the addresses? (and do you think the OmiseGo Solution is a good one?)

Comment: EIP 20 complaint tokens generate a `Transfer(from,to,value)`. If you listen to such events you should be able to collect all token holders.